# Row reduction and generating sets of a finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let us suppose that we have a finite abelian subgroup which is generated by 2 elements $A,B$. On the other hand, define the following 3 "actions":

1. Changing $\{A,B\}$ for $\{B,A\}$.
2. Changing $\{A,B\}$ for $\{A^{-1},B\}$.
3. Changing $\{A,B\}$ for $\{A,AB\}$.

**Question:** Is it true that two sets $\{E,F\}$ and $\{C,D\}$ generate the subgroup $\langle A,B\rangle$ if and only if we can perform a sequence of operations of the form (1)-(3) from one set to the other set?

I've checked some examples and it worked but I couldn't come with a proof, nor a counterexample. It sounds as operations (1)-(3) are like elementary operations and we are saying that two sets generate the sugbroup if and only if the matrix formed by its powers are row equivalent, but I don't know how to formalize it. Is maybe a deeper theory which links these two concepts of generating a subgroup and row reduction of matrices in $\operatorname{Mat}(n\times n,\mathbb{Z})$? Thanks!

Comment: Why name three sets of generators? Isn't this a question about two sets of generators? That is, I think the question you meant to ask was "is it true that two sets generate *the same subgroup* if and only if..."

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it's about two sets of generators.

Comment: The change of type 1 does nothing because $\{A,B\} = \{B,A\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can think of an ordered pair of generators for a finite abelian group $A$ abstractly as a surjective homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z}^2 \twoheadrightarrow A$. Given this setup there are two obvious ways to produce new such surjective homomorphisms: either precompose by an element of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2) \cong GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, or postcompose by an element of $\text{Aut}(A)$. Your three moves all correspond to precomposing by invertible elementary matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, specifically the matrices

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{cc} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$$

and these are known to generate $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (this does not follow from the same result over a field but it is still true).

So the question from here is whether the elements of $\text{Aut}(A)$ can produce generators that $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ can't. From here, following Derek's answer, we can consider $A = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $f : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^2$ the obvious quotient map, corresponding to the pair of generators $\{ (1, 0), (0, 1) \}$. This group has automorphism group $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, and now we can ask: is the reduction $\bmod n$ map

$$GL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$$

surjective? If not, an element of the complement of the image produces a pair of generators which can't be obtained from $\{ (1, 0), (0, 1) \}$ using $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

The answer is that this map is not surjective unless possibly $n = 2, 3, 4, 6$ (the case $n = 1$ is degenerate so I am ignoring it), and the reason is that an element of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ must have determinant $\pm 1$ but an element of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ has a determinant in the group of units $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}^{\times}$ (and the determinant is surjective), which has elements other than $\pm 1$ except for the above values of $n$ (exactly the values of $n$ for which $\varphi(n) \le 2$).

Derek's counterexample can be obtained in this way by taking $n = 8$ and using the matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{array} \right]$ which has determinant $3 \not\equiv \pm 1 \bmod 8$ but the smallest counterexample should occur when $n = 5$ (although the $n = 4$ case may also end up being troublesome), and we can take the same matrix as above or $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{array} \right]$.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for all your explanation and all the details!

Answer (score 3):

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}/8 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/8$ with $A = (1,0)$, $B=(0,1)$.

I don't believe that the generating set $\{(1,0),(0,3)\}$ can be obtained by using the specified operations.

My proof of this is based on a calculation in Magma.  Using the operations on ordered $2$-element generating sets, I found $768$ ordered generating sets, but they did not include $\{(1,0),(0,3)\}$.

In fact there are exactly two equivalence classes of $2$-element generating sets, both containing $768$ (ordered) elements, with representatives $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $\{(1,0),(0,3)\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help sir!